# Redirection rule for redirecting the child pages along with parent page

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect pages of my site to the new site with a redirection rule, which should also be able to redirect the child pages of that particular page without writing any redirect for each child pages. Currently, I am using this:

```
redirect /courses/chemistry/5-13-organic-chemistry-ii-fall-2003 
http://hdl.handle.net/123456789/286
```

but in this case, we are only able to redirect this particular page, but not the child pages (it gives 404 in case of child pages). I have tried the code below also in .htaccess file, but it didn't work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^/courses/chemistry/5-13-organic-chemistry-ii-fall-2003 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://hdl.handle.net/123456789/286/$1 [R=301,L]
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only match host name using `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable.

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^courses/chemistry/5-13-organic-chemistry-ii-fall-2003(.*)$ http://hdl.handle.net/123456789/286$1 [R=302,L,NC,NE]
```

Change `302` to `301` once you make sure it is working for you.

Comment: thanks a lot. I just omitted NC,NE from [R=302,L,NC,NE] and changed 302 to 301. It worked. thanks  a ton :)

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: hi anubhava!...just a quick question on this. This works only for this one line if i have to redirect several URLs then what should i add as its not working if i add several URLs for redirection....Looking for your help...Thanks in advance!

Comment: hey it not accepting my click for you because there should be minimum 15 reputation to do so and sadly i just have 9.. :(

Comment: No that click is for upvote. There is a tick mark below my answer that you can click and it will turn green. You will also get bonus for accepting it.

Comment: Also for supporting several URLs can you tell me example of other source and target URLs.